# i can't get all members

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

My code

```
case 'test': {
            
            msg.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
                if(!member.user.bot){

          msg.author.send(`Logs : Member ${member.user.username}!`);
                }
            });
            return;
        }
```

I can't get all the members to take me only one once it worked but due to some time it doesn't work anymore. Is there a delay at api or how should I order?

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the members using [`GuildMemberManager.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch). If you provide no arguments, it will fetch all members from a guild:

```js
msg.guild.members.fetch()
  .then(members => {
    members.each((m) => console.log(m.displayName));
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```